# Javascript Datejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I was looking through some pages when I stumbled across [this open source JavaScript date library: Datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/). Now I've been trying to use it but everytime I try any function like:

```
$(function() { Date.today().toLongDateString() } );
```

or even only

```
Date.today().toLongDateString()
```

withing  tags, I get errors when the webpage loads, it tells me Date.today() is not a function but it appears as such in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) I've been at this for like almost 2 hours now xD it's driving me crazy and I know I just probably overlooked something...

I loaded the:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/dia_hora/date_es-MX.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have the latest release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the script is not getting loaded. Put an alert('hello'); at the beginning of the script and see if you get that popup when the page loads.

Comment: Try making a call to DateJS without first loading the jQuery libs, maybe jQuery is interfering?

Comment: nope, I removed the jQuery file, still nothing =( I could actually write the js myself since it's not that difficult, but I don't know how to append it on the fly to the spot where I want it

Comment: Try posting your problem on the datejs mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/datejs/topics?pli=1 . Put in a link to this question, I must admit it does seem rather odd that it's failing as you described. Someone there should be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Are your script path and filename correct? You wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/dia_hora/date_es-MX.js"></script>
```

But according to the ["Getting Started" page of the project](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/), it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/dia_hora/date-es-MX.js"></script>
```

There are two hyphens in the original file: "date-es-MX.js", not an underscore. Or did you rename the file?

Check if the file correctly loads using [Firefox Firebug (network tab)](http://getfirebug.com/net.html) or [FiddlerTool](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) if you're using Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the javascript file is incorrect.

**OR**

You have a syntax error in a Javascript file that is being loaded before this one.  I believe the browser will stop trying to interpret the rest of the Javascript as soon as an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try having the JS Console open in Chrome or Firefox or Safari - you will get a much better idea of what the error is.  JS Console has saved me hours or even days - I remember how I used to get frustrated about not being able to tell what happened when JS silently failed.
But with JS Console it's never a silent fail - you get some hint in the error message however small.